# How to convert milliseconds into a readable date Minutes:Seconds Format?

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript I have a variable Time in milliseconds.

I would like to know if there is any build-in function to convert **efficiently** this value to `Minutes:Seconds` format.

If not could you please point me out a utility function.

Example:

FROM

```
462000 milliseconds
```

TO

```
7:42
```

Comment: I know this isn't _efficient_, but I'd just `new Date(462000).toString().match(/\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}/)[0]` - If you know it's always going to be less than 24 hours.

Comment: I thought the same solutions, but I'm not sure about it is efficiency ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks guys for your support, at th end I came up with this solution. I hope it can helps others.

Use:

```
var videoDuration = convertMillisecondsToDigitalClock(18050200).clock; // CONVERT DATE TO DIGITAL FORMAT
```

---

```
// CONVERT MILLISECONDS TO DIGITAL CLOCK FORMAT
function convertMillisecondsToDigitalClock(ms) {
    hours = Math.floor(ms / 3600000), // 1 Hour = 36000 Milliseconds
    minutes = Math.floor((ms % 3600000) / 60000), // 1 Minutes = 60000 Milliseconds
    seconds = Math.floor(((ms % 360000) % 60000) / 1000) // 1 Second = 1000 Milliseconds
        return {
        hours : hours,
        minutes : minutes,
        seconds : seconds,
        clock : hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds
    };
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Just create a `Date` object and pass the milliseconds as a parameter.

```
var date = new Date(milliseconds);
var h = date.getHours();
var m = date.getMinutes();
var s = date.getSeconds();
alert(((h * 60) + m) + ":" + s);
```

Comment: Seems I was a little to fast on this one, fixed it :)

Comment: This does `Hours:Minutes:Seconds` *not* `Minutes:Seconds`.

Comment: @GibboK Nope. Try with `4062000`

Comment: For me it does actually, it gives 0:0 since hours are ignored, if you want the hours as well, just make it `alert(((h * 60) + m) + ":" + s);`

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom the problem starts with `60 * 60 * 1000`.

Comment: @GerritBertier 1. Hours are *not* ignored in your current answer. 2. You should put the `h*60+m` stuff in your answer as this is what GibboK asked for.

Comment: it gives wrong minutes and seconds if they are less than 1 day

Comment: How is that? Please do keep in mind your local time offset from UTC time.

Answer (score 3):

In case you already using [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) in your project, you can use the [moment.duration](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/creating/) function

You can use it like this

```
var mm = moment.duration(37250000);
console.log(mm.hours() + ':' + mm.minutes() + ':' + mm.seconds());
```

output: *10:20:50*

See [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/poboxicake/edit?html,js,console,output) sample

Comment: This will give output as 1:2:5 if proper input is provided. not as 1:02:05.

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to make the conversion oneself:

```
var t = 462000
parseInt(t / 1000 / 60) + ":" + (t / 1000 % 60)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may like **pretty-ms** npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/pretty-ms
If that what you are searching. Headless nice formatting (**time in the units that are needed as ms grow**), personalisable, and cover different situations. Small and efficient for what it cover.

Answer (score 0):

```
function msToMS(ms) {
    var M = Math.floor(ms / 60000);
    ms -= M * 60000;
    var S = ms / 1000;
    return M + ":" + S;
}
```